# SkyDrive hangs on sync in Windows 8 desktop

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I have the integrated SkyDrive client installed on my Windows 8 laptop. Every time I connect to wifi, SkyDrive just hangs with a message like "Uploading 8.9KB of 3.4MB, 113 files remaining" (depending, of course, on the actual files waiting to sync) while the system tray icon churns.

I used my laptop disconnected all day and connect to wifi at home at night, when I'd like to sync everything. Right now the only work around is to exit and restart SkyDrive. Once I restart it, everything works fine and SkyDrive will sync as I work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Uploading all the files may take a while.

When it is done you can also change what items are being downloaded from your SkyDrive.

1. Right Click on the SkyDrive icon in the taskbar
2. Then press settings
3. Then head on over to the 'Choose Folders' tab
4. Next you press the 'Choose Folders' button
5. Choose what you want to sync 'All files and folders on my Skydrive' or Choose folders to sync. If you choose 'Choose folders to sync' you can then select what folders you want to sync
6. Then press 'Ok' and then 'Ok'

To check what is being uploaded follow these:

1. Go to C:\Users\USERNAME\SkyDrive

There you can see what is being uploaded. You can then stop things uploading when you want by deleting the file or folder from the SkyDrive folder.

Hope that helped